# Keep same component in different streams in-sync in Rational Team Concert

Tags: version-control, synchronization, rational-team-concert, ibm-rational

We have a Client/Server-project where there are three components:

- Client
- Server
- BaseLibrary

Both client and server reference to the BaseLibrary. Therefore I created two streams:

- Server Stream includes components Server and BaseLibrary
- Client Stream includes components Client and BaseLibrary

Now if I make changes to the BaseLibrary in one stream they aren't present in the other. Is there a way to keep a component in-sync over different streams with RTC 2?

I also tried to set up the flow target for each other stream, but that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flow target between *Streams* are just here to help you visualize where the deliver/accept flow should happen: it is a visualization tool which you can use when creating a "Flow diagram".

In 3.0.1, you can actually [show pending changes from one Stream to another](https://jazz.net/library/article/649#Example_showPendingChanges).

[image: show pending changes] [image: pending changes]

Now you could setup a build definition and **[use the post-build Deliver](https://jazz.net/library/article/649#Tip2)** in order to deliver automatically from one Stream to the other:

[image: post deliver]

> In this scenario "TeamA" still uses the same trigger policy (to ensure anything they deliver has been validated), however now they are only delivering their single component to the "Integration Stream". In this situation there is no "green" stream, and the Release Engineer no longer has to deliver changes to the integration stream since it is now automated.
>
> Also note from the above Figure that the two checkboxes "`Add components to deliver if they do not exist in the deliver target`" and "`Remove components from the deliver target if they do not exist in the build workspace`" are NOT checked.
> It is recommended to not propagate component additions / deletions to an integration stream via some automated mechanism. The last thing the team would want is to have all other components removed from the integration stream because someone accidentally modified their team's stream.
> The adding or removing of components should be done manually by the Release Engineer in these cases.
> For example, if the team needs a new component, they should first add it to their stream, and deliver it to the integration stream. They would then modify the "`Components to deliver`" selection in the "`Post-build Deliver`" tab to include this new component and have it automatically delivered afterwards